# How to check pdf files from mobile storage and list the name by consensus with dynamic list view

Tags: android, pdf

I have dynamic listView linked with JSONArray, in the adapter i'm trying to read the storage to check if the pdf file is downloaded already the Button text will be View and will call View method but if the the file not there the Button text will be Download and will call Download method.

I have been trying this code but it's not work

```
String path2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/materialpdffolder/";
    File path = new File(path2);


    File list[] = path.listFiles();



     for( int i=0; i < materialList.size() ; i++)
    {
        for( int x=0; x <= list.length ; x++) {

        if (list[x].getName() != null) {
            if (list[x].getName().equals(materialList.get(position).getMaterial_file_name().toString())) {
            DVmaterial.setText("View(" + materialList.get(position).getMaterial_file_name().toString() +")" );
        }}else
        {
            DVmaterial.setText("Download(" + materialList.get(position).getMaterial_file_name().toString() + ")");
        }

        }
    }
```

The problem is when there’s no file, the application is stack and give error and not give any results for `list[x].get Name()` and when I use `materiallist.size()` for for looping it is doesn’tgive a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to change with this code

```
if (list[x].getName() != null) {
            if (list[x].getName().equals(materialList.get(position).getMaterial_file_name().toString())) {
            DVmaterial.setText("View(" + materialList.get(position).getMaterial_file_name().toString() +")" );
        }else
        {
            DVmaterial.setText("Download(" + materialList.get(position).getMaterial_file_name().toString() + ")");
        }
}
```

Remove one bracket from `}}else` and put it end of `else`

Comment: The problem is when there’s no file, the application is stack and give error and not give any results for `list[x].get Name()` and when I use `materiallist.size()` for for looping it is doesn’tgive a correct answer